# Use Xscreensaver at the login screen

Tags: lightdm, xscreensaver

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04 and I'd like to show a carousel of images as  screeensaver. I installed Xscreensaver and it works fine when a user is logged in but I can't make it work at the login screen. Reading the Xscreensaver manual I found that it's possible to do so with GDM but it doesn't mention LightDM.

Is there any way to execute Xscreensaver at the LightDM login screen?